# How can I use nested for loop to index this basic problem

Tags: matlab

I have a simple nested for loop indexing problem that I'm unable to solve.
I would like to index x from 1:NaNb using only i and j. So I would like to replace "a" in the following code with combination of i and j where it will index from 1 to Na*Nb. The two for loops cannot be changed as they are used for other calculations. The only thing that should be modified is "a". Will appreciate for any suggestions. Thank you in advance!

```
for i = 1:Na
    for j = 1:Nb
        x(a) = ABC; 
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With the limit context and variable types/declarations, this is what I came up with. The index of `x()` is calculated by using a combination of `i` and `j`.

### Method 1:

```
Na = 10;
Nb = 10;

x = strings(1,Na*Nb);

for i = 1:Na
    for j = 1:Nb
        x(1,((i-1)*Na + j)) = 'ABC'; 
    end
end
```

### Method 2:

```
Na = 10;
Nb = 10;

x = strings(1,Na*Nb);
Index = 1;

for i = 1:Na
    for j = 1:Nb
        x(Index) = 'ABC'; 
        Index = Index + 1;
    end
end
```

**If ABC is a variable of type integer**

```
Na = 10;
Nb = 10;
ABC = 1;
x = zeros(1,Na*Nb);

for i = 1:Na
    for j = 1:Nb
        x(1,((i-1)*Na + j)) = ABC; 
    end
end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**

Comment: Thank you! The second method is exactly what I'm looking for. I just simply want to store from 1 to Na*Nb.